# Alguém poderia me explicar como é que essa nova navegation drawer funciona?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Eu estou começando a estudar android, e depois da atualização 3.5 do android studio a template de navegation drawer mudou muito e como estou começando a estudar,estou totalmente perdido,alguém poderia me explicar onde fica a chamada de fragment e como eu poderia executar um metodo ao clicar em algum item da navegation drawer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

}

GalleryFragment

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    galleryViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
    galleryViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    });
    return root;
}
```

}
GalleryViewModel

```
public class GalleryViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

public GalleryViewModel() {
    mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
    mText.setValue("This is gallery fragment");
}

public LiveData<String> getText() {
    return mText;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Enfrentei o mesmo problema, na verdade trata-se de um erro do androidstudio na versão 3.5. Em seu arquivo activity_main.xml, verifique se O navigationView está antes do include. Caso esteja, deixe-o depois do include que seu drawer vai funcionar corretamente. Para impedir que aconteça novamente pode seguir esse [post aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591080/android-studio-3-5-refactor-issue):

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```